# Is there a way to check if my app is above 20Mb?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to check if my app is above 20Mb after I submitted my application through xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload the app, you had to go ahead and prepare a binary; just check the file size of that. The size of the file after compression is the one that counts.

Comment: I thought you are allowed to upload an app with size > 20 Mb but just requires the download from iTunes and not on the device?

Comment: Ah, what am I thinking, of course that's right. I'll modify my answer to remove that second line -- the first one's correct, though! It's the zipped size that matters.

Comment: I don't see the binary, the whole process is behind the scenes now.

Comment: got it, I don't think you can access it again -- I'd just create a new build and compare. If it's too big, and you think you can slim it down, you can always reject the binary and submit again, or just wait until an update. Congrats on submitting!